# Why is `&` reserved in Idris 2? What is it used for?

Tags: idris

Why can I not use `&` as an operator in Idris 2? What is it used for? I tried searching the source code of the compiler and tests but came up with nothing.

Comment: I think at some point there was a plan to use it for a "borrowing" modality, not sure if that's still in the pipeline